# How to change a set bounty

Tags: support

Is it possible to increase bounty?

Like I have set bounty to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/363856/instruction-per-cycle-vs-increased-cycle-count) question to 100, but I would like to raise it to 150. Does the system allow me to do so?

Comment: Not really I guess, but you can just offer another bounty.

Comment: [Related topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3742/can-i-promise-a-bounty-but-only-put-it-in-place-once-there-is-an-acceptable-ans).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change it by yourself. You can either wait for the bounty to end and start a new one.

Another option is to flag the post for moderator attention and mention about wanting to increase the bounty. Mods can then refund the existing bounty and you can offer a new one.

Be aware that with this, a new bounty is created and as a result, if someone had originally posted an answer after the bounty was issued the first time, once the second bounty has run it's course and you didn't allocate the bounty, the person who posted the answer may not be automatically awarded the bounty rep.

Comment: @harper89 yeah, that's what my first line says

Comment: I misread the second line. I read it as the mod would erase the current bounty and allow you to offer a new one before awarding one. I will delete my comments so theres no confusion :)