# What to do if open bounty for question that can't be solved

Tags: discussion, bounty

I made [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/679202/how-to-get-side-buttons-working-on-mouse-in-linux-running-in-vmware-player) and forgot to mention the operating system was running as a virtual machine. It turns out, as such,  I cannot accomplish what I set out to do. Should I award the bounty to the one answer or should I let it expire?

Answer (score 6):

Bounties can't be refunded, so your choices are indeed to either award it or let it expire. If it expires, then half its value will be awarded to the highest-ranked answer with a score of at least 2. For specific details on how bounties are automatically awarded when the user does not manually award them, [see this help center entry](https://superuser.com/help/bounty).

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

It's up to you whether to award it or not. Generally speaking, you should try to award the bounty to the most-deserving answer. If a particular answer helped you out - even if it didn't solve the final question - then there's no problem with awarding the bounty. Sometimes the answer of "you can't do that" is the most valuable answer of all.

Answer (score 6):

I have an obvious bias here - since I answered the question, and as far as I'm concerned, covered what was *initially* asked. There was a *significant* amount of back and forth chatter before you mentioned you were running a VM. I think part of the problem here is you shifted the goalpost rather too late - its a significantly more complex question for me to replicate now, than it was for me to answer initially.

Considering that you were walked through parts of the install process (granted by others as well as myself), and you got the software installed before you mentioned it was a VM - , I consider the original question (on how to get a razer mouse working in linux answered). The best solution (to me, taking into account the previous paragraph) would be to roll back to the last edit before mentioning it was a VM, awarding the bounty, and marking my answer as answered.

Then you could ask a second question, about generically passing through HID devices to vmware player. And if you ask nicely (that is to say, you let me kniow you want me to, I'll put up a 100 reputation bounty for you under my usual rules - if you find an answer that works, let me know, and I'll award it), since this isn't about the reputation at all for me.

And please, in future, don't *change the question* after you've put up a bounty.

Under *other* circumstances, you can award second, or further bounties - [I've done so myself](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3742/can-i-promise-a-bounty-but-only-put-it-in-place-once-there-is-an-acceptable-ans).

Comment: Maybe mentioning to not change *the meaning* of the question, after posting the bounty