# Could this bounty be left open forever?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty, asking-questions

I opened [this bounty](https://superuser.com/questions/710495/is-it-possible-to-run-corona-sdk-on-reactos-or-wine), no answers yet and probably no solutions will be given anytime soon, because I really asked a hard, maybe impossible question, I know that and that's why I opened a bounty.

The problem itself is solved, I got a windows XP image, but I would like to know the answer to my question. I don't want that the bounty goes for nothing. I am not asking for a refund and I am aware that this is an impossible thing, probably.

All I want is for my bounty to be open forever, maybe two years from now, there will be a solution, maybe they'll create a corona that runs on wine or natively on linux, then someone would answer my question and I'll be giving him the bounty. That way I get my answer, he gets his bounty and we're both happy.

If it goes to nothing, no one wins, I don't get my answer, I lose rep, and the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bounty process is set up in the way it is and it will probably not be changed any time soon.

If there is no new answer to the question you put a bounty on, then you will get the bounty refunded. If someone posts an answer and it receives at least 2 upvotes, then the author of that answer will receive half the bounty or the full bounty if you manually give it to them for their answer.

Comment: I get refunded? i didn't know that's possible, I thought it goes to nothing

Comment: @Fischer: Reputation is like energy, it never disappears, it only transfers :)

Comment: you should tell them [that here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221328/could-this-bounty-be-left-open-forever) they gave me 10 downvotes just because i said that I don't want my rep to go to nothingness, i didn't know i get refunded

Comment: I'm afraid that's not correct. Bounties are never refunded. They are paid up front – and the rep is gone.

Comment: @slhck  you're right the bounty has expired, the rep is gone...

Comment: This answer is wrong. Bounties are **not** refunded, except when a moderator forcibly terminates it.

Answer (score 2):

No, not really. I've actually had similar issues with an answer in the past - [I ended up posting a low bounty, then promising a higher bounty once answered](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3742/can-i-promise-a-bounty-but-only-put-it-in-place-once-there-is-an-acceptable-ans). Obviously its on a honour system, and you're going to have to follow up (and It was a special case) but thats one way to handle it.